# Find every permutation of an array in Ruby, including permutations with sub arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, permutation

Consider an array: `[4, 6, 9]`

Require all the permutations: (one, two and three digit ones)

```
[[9],
 [6],
 [4],
 [9, 6],
 [9, 4],
 [6, 9],
 [6, 4],
 [4, 9],
 [4, 6],
 [9, 6, 4],
 [9, 4, 6],
 [6, 9, 4],
 [6, 4, 9],
 [4, 9, 6],
 [4, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: I can't say I would recommend the following, but it does work: `([4,6,9]+[nil,nil]).permutation(3).map(&:compact).uniq`.

Comment: Hmm, thats seems to be inefficient and difficult to be made a generic one liner.

Comment: Jikku, you've expressed my thoughts exactly; still, I thought it deserved a comment (certainly not an answer!) because it was good exercise for the little grey cells. I wasn't familiar with Thiruvananthapuram. I see it's only a small town, just 1.6 million +-.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yup Thiruvananthapuram is a small city in India. You should visit here once, its a beautiful city. I actually was quite impressed with the way you thought about including `nils` and removing it later, but while trying to refine it, I stumbled on many places. Anyways, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recording this question and my own finding as I didn't find anything simple enough while searching. Perhaps this may help someone:

```
a = [4, 6, 9]
(1..a.length).flat_map { |n| a.permutation(n).to_a }
```

And for every combination, just switch the method, like so:

```
a = [4, 6, 9]
(1..a.length).flat_map { |n| a.combination(n).to_a }
```