# Ruby Create all permutations of array and remove items

Tags: arrays, ruby, permutation

I would like to have the following permutation array from the array `[1,2]`:

```
[1]
[2]
[1,2]
[2,1]
```

I cannot think how to remove an item from the permutation like this.

Thank you.

Comment: `[1, 2].permutation.to_a + [1, 2].zip`

Comment: what would be the expected results for `[1, 2, 3]` or `[2, 1, 2]`?

Comment: @w0lf the same as [1,2,3].permutation.to_a as well as [1,2][2,1][3,1][1,3][3,2][2,3][1][2][3], I believe.

Comment: don't know if this is a duplicate, but I find it related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28296301/390819

Comment: these are not permutations of an array, they look like union of subsets permutations. Please be more specific, and more clear about you mean by removing an item from the resulting collection.

Comment: Please mention what you have tried till now. Also, go through this document.
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation